# Combine multiple text files into one file

Tags: command-line

I am using the unix `pr` command to combine multiple text files into one text file:

```
pr -F *files > newfile
```

Each file is a different length, a different number of lines. I am mostly happy with the result, I like that it includes the name of the original text file followed by the contents of that file. However, I would like to eliminate the blank lines in between the name of the original text file and it's contents. I only want blank lines between the different text files to separate each. Also, it prints the character `^L` after the contents of each text file, and I would like to eliminate that character.

Each file read in is also given a 'page' number. Only one file is longer than the 66 line default. that file ends up being spit into 2 'pages', and is split into 2 sections divided by blank lines. Is it possible to write that text in continuously without it being split?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the AWK utility:

```
awk 'FNR==1{print ""}{print}' *files > newfile
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653063/how-do-i-include-a-blank-line-between-files-im-concatenating-with-cat

Comment: thank you for you suggestion. however, -T isn't being recognized. i'm working on mac os x if that matters.

Comment: unfortunately, -t creates the same type of file that cat does, no break between text files read in.

Comment: thank you Radu. that just about gets me what i want! sorry, i realize now that i am posting to the wrong place, as i see the notification about being off-topic. i thank you for you help!

Answer (score 16):

To have empty lines betwen files:

```
cat file1 newline file2 newline file3 > newfile
```

Where 'newline' is file with empty line.

Comment: Can you clarify how to make the file `newline`? Some text edtiors will automatically append an end-of-line character to the last line, and others will not, so some people may experience problems making this file properly. To put this another way: does a zero-length file have zero lines, or one line?

Comment: vim newline
in vim
    :wq
Thats it.

Comment: As long as I see, "cat" puts new line automatically between each file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cat` to dump the text of files into one file with:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 > newfile
```

Comment: Unfortunately `cat` doesn't fulfill any of the other requirements.

Comment: yes, thank you. but cat just lists the contents of each file without the original text file name and it also lists the contents of each file one after another with no break in between. i need at least 1 blank line between the contents of each text file in the new one big file.

Answer (score 2):

```
for file in *.txt; do (cat "${file}"; echo) >> concatenated.txt; done
```

The above will append the contents of eacb txt file into concatenated.txt adding a new line between them.